# How to Get a Lexical Analyzer to analyze each character entered (minus spaces)?

Tags: java, analyzer, lexical

I'm currently trying to create a lexical analyzer in Java, and I'm having some difficulties getting the analyzer to analyze each character entered. I currently have it analyzing the code with spaces being put in between each character, but the requirements are that the analyzer should be able to detect "(sum" as "(" and "sum", so analyzing using spaces to separate them doesn't work.

My code isn't very efficient, but it currently works to analyze the entered text by using spaces in between the two. Is there a way to analyze each character entered, rather than using " " to separate them?

Here is my code:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Math Problem:");
    //input is "(sum + 47) / total"
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,st.countTokens());


    //Displays the header to the information table
    jTextArea1.append("John D. Student, CSCI4200-DA, Fall 2018, Lexical Analyzer \n" + 
                      "******************************************************************************** \n \n");
    //Displays the input value
    jTextArea1.append("Input: " + input + "\n");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //Begin displaying the next token
        jTextArea1.append("Next token is: ");

            String nextItem = st.nextToken();
            if("(".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("LEFT_PAREN" + "     " + "Next lexeme is " + nextItem + "\n");
            }
            else if("sum".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("IDENT" + "              " + "Next Lexeme is " + "sum" + "\n");
            }
            else if("+".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("ADD_OP" + "           " + "Next lexeme is " + nextItem + "\n");
            }
            else if("47".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("INT_LIT" + "            " + "Next lexeme is " + "47" + "\n");
            }
            else if(")".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("RIGHT_PAREN" + "  " + "Next Lexeme is " + nextItem + "\n");
            }
            else if("/".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("DIV_OP" + "            " + "Next lexeme is " + nextItem + "\n");
            }
            else if("total".equals(nextItem)) {
                jTextArea1.append("IDENT" + "             " + "Next lexeme is " + "total" + "\n");
            }
            else {
                jTextArea1.append("Unknown Character \n");
            }
    }
    //Once the tokens are done, display the finish message
    if(!st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        jTextArea1.append("******************************************************************************** \n \n");
        jTextArea1.append("Next token is: END_OF_FILE" + "     " + "Next lexeme is EOF \n");
        jTextArea1.append("Lexical analysis of the program is complete!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only tokenizing by space right now.  You need to set it to tokenize by special characters like parentheses, plus, minus, multiply, divide any anything else that is not an alpha numeric character, as well as the white space.  Once you get this done going through the tokens will be much easier for parsing the problem,

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above need more delimiters for tokenizing.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, " ()+-");
```

Is a starting example of what I mean, white space, parentheses, plus and minus.  Add more characters to the delimiter string to tokenize by those as well.

You should never see if a string token equals a certain number this will block further progress.

Use something like

```
int newnum = Integer.ParseInt(nextItem);
```

after you do an initial check to see if it an integer of course.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your response. That makes a lot more sense. Would there be a way to tokenize something like "sum" or "total" along with the plus, minus, etc? Especially if they're right next to each other.

Like at the beginning of the input, it's "(sum" but I need a way to tokenize "(" and "sum" separately

Comment: Learning time.  Make the program output the entire tokenizer after you add in all the delimiters you want and see what kind of tokens pop out and see if you need to add in any kind of alpha-numeric delimiters.  Im not about to give you the whole problem :-) I should have showed you enough to solve your initial question.  If you have any questions about how a function acts simply put a loop output and see what it does.

Comment: Please vote up my answer if it solved your problem :-)